# Powershell persistent mapped drive won't save credentials for next logon

Tags: powershell, batch-file, vbscript

So I have this powershell (or vbs or batch) script I'm trying to write.  All it needs to do is a map a network drive persistently using alternate credentials.  For some reason, it seems like the credentials aren't persisting.  It maps fine initially then on login the drive will have a red X and when trying to open it I'll get prompted for the password.

When running powershell as the admin, upon re-logon, the drive isn't even shown anymore.  I'm guessing because of a scope issue, but I thought the global flag was supposed to take care of that?

I've also tried the "net use" method and the "Wscript.Network" method from within powershell... same results.

I'm new-ish to windows scripting so it's probably something really dumb.  Here's the essentials of the script I'm using.  I'm pasting it directly into the powershell window.  Where have I gone astray?

```
$user = "USERNAME"
$pass = "PASSWORD"

$cur_share = "\\192.168.1.100\websites"

$drive = "X"

$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pass -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, $PWord

New-PSDrive -Name $drive -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root $cur_share -Scope "Global" -Persist -Credential $Credential
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Jon.  Just as you post that I found a workable solution.  The key is to store the credential in the manage before using the network path.

```
$result = cmdkey /add: "192.168.1.100" /user: "USERNAME" /pass: "PASSWORD"
```

That stores the credentials persistenty.  Then mapping the drives persistently works with no password prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing this behavior because you are using alternate credentials. If I use your code with my own credentials the drive persists even across reboots but if I use alternate credentials it does not. This is apparently as designed.

Relevant details from the cmdlet help:

> Mapped network drives are specific to a user account. Mapped network
>   drives that you create in sessions that are started by using the Run
>   as administrator option or by using the credential of another user are
>   not visible in a session that was started without explicit
>   credentials, or by using the credentials of the current user.

Reference:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849829.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396